# Get the first visible column in Ultragrid

Tags: .net, vb.net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I am having number of columns in my `ultragrid` with userdefined `visible` and `invisible` operations. Now i have to check wheather the column is the first `column` in the grid. since i have some `columns` which is binded explicitly with the help of `index` i cant get the column. Always it shows the same `column` as the First one.

//Code

```
For Each UltraGridColumn In Me.TransactionsGrid.Rows.Band.Columns

   'Get the first cell column in the grid
   UltraGridCell = UltraGridRow.Cells(UltraGridColumn)

   If ('Check Here') Then

      'Set the cell image
      UltraGridCell.Appearance.Image = My.Resources.Tran_comment_161
      UltraGridCell.Appearance.ImageHAlign = HAlign.Right
      UltraGridCell.Appearance.ImageVAlign = VAlign.Top

   Else
      UltraGridCell.Appearance.ResetImage()
   End If
Next
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: I don't really get what you want. Do you simply want to get the first column of your grid?

Comment: Yes. Since i have some of the columns which are binded explicitly if i hide the first column then the code should show the 2nd column as first which is now visible in the grid as first column. am i clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a flag to check which column is selected, this code works fine.

```
For Each UltraGridColumn In Me.TransactionsGrid.Rows.Band.Columns

       'Get the first cell column in the grid
       UltraGridCell = UltraGridRow.Cells(UltraGridColumn)

       If ('Check Here') Then

          'Set the cell image
          UltraGridCell.Appearance.Image = My.Resources.Tran_comment_161
          UltraGridCell.Appearance.ImageHAlign = HAlign.Right
          UltraGridCell.Appearance.ImageVAlign = VAlign.Top

       Else
          UltraGridCell.Appearance.ResetImage()
       End If
    Next 

 If (blnFlag) Then
                    Dim i = 0
                    For Each UltraGridColumn In Me.TransactionsGrid.Rows.Band.Columns

                        'Get the first cell of the column in the grid
                        UltraGridCell = UltraGridRow.Cells(UltraGridColumn)

                        If (UltraGridColumn.Hidden = False And i = 0) Then

                            'Set the cell image
                            UltraGridCell.Appearance.Image = My.Resources.Tran_comment_161
                            UltraGridCell.Appearance.ImageHAlign = HAlign.Right
                            UltraGridCell.Appearance.ImageVAlign = VAlign.Top
                            i += 1
                        Else
                            'Reset the image if other column
                            UltraGridCell.Appearance.ResetImage()
                        End If

                    Next
  End If
```

Answer (score 1):

I am adding an alternative answer as it answered the question that is asked by the title and may be what people are looking for if they come across this question.

The WinGrid will have one or more ColScrollRegions that give a scrollable region of headers and off of the ColScrollRegion there is a [VisibleHeaders](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/Current/CLR4.0/?page=Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v13.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ColScrollRegion~VisibleHeaders.html) property that exposes the visible headers for the scroll region.

Note that this will provide the first visible column even if the grid is scrolled to the right and may not be the first column in the grid. When the scroll position of the scroll region is all the way to the left, then the first header in the [VisibleHeadersCollection](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/Current/CLR4.0/?page=Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v13.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.VisibleHeadersCollection.html) will return the first column in the grid.

The ColScrollRegions are accessed by the ColScrollRegions property on DisplayLayout and you can access the first visible header with:

```
Me.ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.ColScrollRegions(0).VisibleHeaders(0).Header
```

If the header is a ColumnHeader, then it will expose the Column as a property.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
This code will get you the first visible Column.

```
Dim firstCol As UltraGridColumn = Nothing
        For Each col As UltraGridColumn In TransactionsGrid.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns
            If Not col.Hidden Then
                firstCol = col
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If firstCol IsNot Nothing Then
            'Your code here
        End If
```

Comment: Sorry this doesn't work.My first column in the grid is hidden and the 2nd column is shown as the first column. Now the code should show the second column as first since that is visible right now.

Comment: To be more specific and direct i need the firstvisiblecolumn of the grid.